# How to import Trainer and TrainingArguments from transformers?

Tags: python

I use pip to install transformer and I use python 3.9.

When I do

from transformers import  Trainer,TrainingArguments

I get:

> Python 3.9.0 (default, Dec  4 2020, 23:28:57)  [Clang 9.0.0
> (clang-900.0.39.2)] on darwin Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or
> "license" for more information.
>
> > > > from transformers import  Trainer,TrainingArguments Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> > > > "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/utils/import_utils.py",
> > > > line 905, in _get_module
> > > > return importlib.import_module("." + module_name, self.**name**)   File
> > > > "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.0_4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/**init**.py",
> > > > line 127, in import_module
> > > > return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "", line 1030, in _gcd_import   File
> > > > "", line 1007, in _find_and_load   File
> > > > "", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
> > > > File "", line 680, in _load_unlocked
> > > > File "", line 790, in
> > > > exec_module   File "", line 228, in
> > > > _call_with_frames_removed   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py", line
> > > > 172, in 
> > > > import datasets   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/datasets/**init**.py",
> > > > line 3, in 
> > > > from . import mnist   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/datasets/mnist.py", line
> > > > 7, in 
> > > > from ..utils.data_utils import get_file ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>    File "", line 1055, in
> _handle_fromlist   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/utils/import_utils.py",
> line 895, in **getattr**
> module = self._get_module(self._class_to_module[name])   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/utils/import_utils.py",
> line 907, in _get_module
> raise RuntimeError( RuntimeError: Failed to import transformers.trainer because of the following error (look up to see
> its traceback): attempted relative import beyond top-level package

Does anyone faced the same issue or know how to fix it ?

Many thanks,
Ele
Note: When I look into the transformer folder
ls /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/transformers/

> **init**.py
> **pycache** activations.py activations_tf.py benchmark commands configuration_utils.py convert_graph_to_onnx.py
> convert_pytorch_checkpoint_to_tf2.py convert_slow_tokenizer.py
> convert_slow_tokenizers_checkpoints_to_fast.py
> convert_tf_hub_seq_to_seq_bert_to_pytorch.py data debug_utils.py
> deepspeed.py dependency_versions_check.py dependency_versions_table.py
> dynamic_module_utils.py feature_extraction_sequence_utils.py
> feature_extraction_utils.py file_utils.py
> generation_beam_constraints.py generation_beam_search.py
> generation_flax_logits_process.py generation_flax_utils.py
> generation_logits_process.py generation_stopping_criteria.py
> generation_tf_logits_process.py generation_tf_utils.py
> generation_utils.py hf_argparser.py image_utils.py integrations.py
> keras_callbacks.py modelcard.py modeling_flax_outputs.py
> modeling_flax_pytorch_utils.py modeling_flax_utils.py
> modeling_outputs.py modeling_tf_outputs.py
> modeling_tf_pytorch_utils.py modeling_tf_utils.py modeling_utils.py
> models onnx optimization.py optimization_tf.py pipelines
> processing_utils.py py.typed pytorch_utils.py sagemaker
> testing_utils.py tf_utils.py tokenization_utils.py
> tokenization_utils_base.py tokenization_utils_fast.py trainer.py
> trainer_callback.py trainer_pt_utils.py trainer_seq2seq.py
> trainer_tf.py trainer_utils.py training_args.py
> training_args_seq2seq.py training_args_tf.py utils

and when I do
ls utils/

> **init**.py
> **pycache** doc.py dummy_detectron2_objects.py dummy_flax_objects.py dummy_pt_objects.py dummy_scatter_objects.py
> dummy_sentencepiece_and_speech_objects.py
> dummy_sentencepiece_and_tokenizers_objects.py
> dummy_sentencepiece_objects.py dummy_speech_objects.py
> dummy_tf_objects.py dummy_timm_and_vision_objects.py
> dummy_timm_objects.py dummy_tokenizers_objects.py
> dummy_vision_objects.py fx.py generic.py hp_naming.py hub.py
> import_utils.py logging.py model_parallel_utils.py notebook.py
> sentencepiece_model_pb2.py versions.py

Comment: You should have used the "code" markup, not "quote", for your code examples.

Comment: Also note how line breaks in the Markdown text do not translate to line breaks in the rendered output. You need a blank line to separate paragraphs.